# Transparent background - not completely transparent

Tags: sifr

I've implemented sIFR 3 on my site but I'm having a strange issue.

The header is overlaid on a background image which is a gradient. This image is defined in the CSS.
As you can see in the image below, the area covered by the sIFR is a slightly different colour.

<strike>[Header image](http://www.mhsc.nhs.uk/sifrheader.jpg)</strike> (Dead Link)

The code for the replacement is as follows:

```
sIFR.replace(Amasis_MT_font, {
    selector: 'h1.flashHeader',
    css: [
    '.sIFR-root { font-weight:normal; color:#507A9A; leading:-10; width:500px }',
    'a { text-decoration: none }',
    'a:link { color: #507A9A }',
    'a:hover { color: #003366 }'
    ],
    wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that your display is set to 16 bits colors?

Comment: Hi,

it looks like it could be that. I've been viewing directly on the server which seems to only have the ability to display in 16 bit. So I can't test it on there, but your answer sounds accurate.

Thanks.